# Why am I getting 'sequence does not exist' error code?

Tags: oracle

trying to understand why I keep getting this error code when the only solution i can find online is that I might not have the right privileges which isnt the case.

Table

```
create table channelTable (
channelID number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
channelName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
channelDate date NOT NULL,
userName varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
topicCode varchar(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT c_topicCode check(substr(topicCode, 1, 1) not in ('I', 'O', 'Q', 'V', 'Y', 'Z') and regexp_like(topicCode, '^[A-Z]\d')));
```

Sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqChannel
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;
INSERT INTO channelTable (channelID, ChannelName, ChannelDate, UserName, TopicCode)
VALUES (seqchannel1.nextval, 'Bob Loves Science', '03-FEB-2000', 'bob101', 'S1' );
```

Error Code

```
VALUES (seqchannel1.nextval, 'Bob Loves Science', '03-FEB-2000', 'bob101', 'S1' )
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you the literal truth: there is no sequence called `seqchannel1`.  When you created the sequence you called it `seqchannel`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong sequence name.

You have created the sequence with name  `seqchannel` and while using it, you are using `1` following the actual sequence name as `seqchannel1`.

Execute it with `seqchannel.nextval`.